# How to set polynomial (custom) formula in mlr with regr.lm task

Tags: r, mlr

I'm trying to fit a polynomial function (for learning reasons) to the `BostonHousing` data with the `mlr` package.

I'm unable to figure out how to provide a custom formula to the `lm` function used, especially I want to add a polynomial function to one of the input variables (for testing purposes).

How can this best be achieved?

```
library(mlr)

data("BostonHousing", package = "mlbench")

regr.task <- makeRegrTask(data = BostonHousing, target = "medv")
regr.learner <- makeLearner("regr.lm")

# I would like to specify the formula used by "regr.lm" myself, how can this be achieved?

regr.train <- train(regr.learner, regr.task)

lm.results <- getLearnerModel(regr.train)

summary(lm.results) 

Call:                                                                                 
stats::lm(formula = f, data = d)                                                      

Residuals:                                                                            
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max                                               
-15.595  -2.730  -0.518   1.777  26.199                                               

Coefficients:                                                                         
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)                                    
(Intercept)  3.646e+01  5.103e+00   7.144 3.28e-12 ***                                
crim        -1.080e-01  3.286e-02  -3.287 0.001087 **                                 
zn           4.642e-02  1.373e-02   3.382 0.000778 ***                                
indus        2.056e-02  6.150e-02   0.334 0.738288                                    
chas1        2.687e+00  8.616e-01   3.118 0.001925 **                                 
nox         -1.777e+01  3.820e+00  -4.651 4.25e-06 ***                                
rm           3.810e+00  4.179e-01   9.116  < 2e-16 ***                                
age          6.922e-04  1.321e-02   0.052 0.958229                                    
dis         -1.476e+00  1.995e-01  -7.398 6.01e-13 ***                                
rad          3.060e-01  6.635e-02   4.613 5.07e-06 ***                                
tax         -1.233e-02  3.760e-03  -3.280 0.001112 **                                 
ptratio     -9.527e-01  1.308e-01  -7.283 1.31e-12 ***                                
b            9.312e-03  2.686e-03   3.467 0.000573 ***                                
lstat       -5.248e-01  5.072e-02 -10.347  < 2e-16 ***                                
---                                                                                   
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1                        

Residual standard error: 4.745 on 492 degrees of freedom                              
Multiple R-squared:  0.7406,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7338                           
F-statistic: 108.1 on 13 and 492 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this as the purpose of the model is to learn exactly this itself. However, you can easily compute predictions if you already have the formula.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This seems indeed to be the case, I suppose I'm meant to use the base lm function when developing a linear model and the mlr package for more sophisticated techniques.